# Simple Chapter Style

Tags: memoir, chapters

I am using this chapterstyle

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,showtrims,openright,titlepage]{memoir}
\makechapterstyle{VZ23}{%

\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
\renewcommand\printchaptername{}
\renewcommand\chapnumfont{\Huge\bfseries\centering}
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\Huge\scshape\centering}
\renewcommand\afterchapternum{%
\par\nobreak\vskip\midchapskip\hrule\vskip\midchapskip}
\renewcommand\printchapternonum{%
\vspace*{-8.0\onelineskip}
\vphantom{\chapnumfont \thechapter}
\par\nobreak\vskip\midchapskip\hrule\vskip\midchapskip}}

\trimFrame
\settrims{3cm}{5.2cm}
 \settrimmedsize{210mm}{140mm}{1}%
 \settypeblocksize{170mm}{95mm}{.75}

\chapterstyle{VZ23}

\begin{document}

\chapter[NOTIZIA]{NOTIZIA}
\end{document}
```

[image]
But i would not get the line on top of the chaptertitle.
Does anybody know which is the way to do it?

Comment: Without a complete minimal example, it will be impossible for anybody to help who does not recognise the commands you are using and find themselves with the inclination to construct such a document for you. Speaking for myself, I'd try to help if it didn't mean first figuring out what class and packages are needed in order to reproduce your issue, but I'm not about to start searching through all the possibilities before I can even understand the problem. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: See my edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to happen in the case of unnumbered chapters, so I've omitted that formatting here. I'm also not clear whether you want to move the line or eliminate it, so I show examples of both.

I've also commented the code concerning the setting of the page dimensions since your settings are not possible (i.e. `memoir` cannot implement the numbers you request in your MWE as you discover if you ask it to check).

You can eliminate the line altogether:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,showtrims,openright,titlepage]{memoir}
\makechapterstyle{VZ23}{%    
  \renewcommand\chapternamenum{}%
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{}%
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\Huge\bfseries\centering}%
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\Huge\scshape\centering}%
}

\trimFrame
\settrims{3cm}{5.2cm}
\settrimmedsize{210mm}{140mm}{*}% the third argument is the ratio of the first to the second
\settypeblocksize{170mm}{95mm}{*}% ditto
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}% without this, things don't fit on the page!
\setulmargins{*}{*}{1}% ditto
\checkandfixthelayout% you need this after changing the page layout above!

    \chapterstyle{VZ23}

    \begin{document}

      \chapter[NOTIZIA]{NOTIZIA}
    \end{document}
```

[image: no line]

Or you can put the line before the chapter number as in the image in your question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,showtrims,openright,titlepage]{memoir}
\makechapterstyle{VZ23}{%
  \renewcommand\chapternamenum{}%
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{\par\nobreak\vskip\midchapskip\hrule\vskip\midchapskip}%
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\Huge\bfseries\centering}%
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\Huge\scshape\centering}%
}

\trimFrame
\settrims{3cm}{5.2cm}
\settrimmedsize{210mm}{140mm}{*}% the third argument is the ratio of the first to the second
\settypeblocksize{170mm}{95mm}{*}% ditto
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}% without this, things don't fit on the page!
\setulmargins{*}{*}{1}% ditto
\checkandfixthelayout% you need this after changing the page layout above!

\chapterstyle{VZ23}

\begin{document}

  \chapter[NOTIZIA]{NOTIZIA}
\end{document}
```

[image: rule first]